# How do I run perfmon against a remote machine?

Tags: perfmon

For starters I'm trying to do this from a Windows 7 box to a Windows 7 box.

I know the simple answer should be to enter \\computername where it says "Select Counters From Computer". Trouble is, every time I do that I get an error message that says "Unable to connect to machine"

I know the machine is out there and accessible, because I can bring up windows explorer and enter \\computername\c$ in the explorer bar and then can browse their c drive. So the machine is out there.

Are there special permissions for perfmon? Is here a service which needs to be running on the remote machine?

Answer (score 3):

You need RPC between the machines. The endpoint mapper is TCP 135, which then negotiates high-numbered ephemeral ports on which to send subsequent traffic.

Check your firewalls, both hardware and Windows Firewall.

`\\computername\c$` works because it does not require RPC, only TCP 445. (AKA Direct-hosted SMB.) And since you can access an admin share, it's safe to assume that you already have administrative permissions on the target machine.

Also I suppose you need to check the RPC and RPC Endpoint Mapper services on the machines, but I assumed those services are running since you'd be having bigger problems if they weren't.

Comment: PortQRY UI is a good way to test RPC connectivity if needed.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

Answer (score 0):

Not if you can get to C$ - this is a admin only share.  I notice you only put one slash at the beginning of your NetBIOS name.  Have you tried \\computername\c$, or even just computername.domain.com (or whatever your domain is)?  The later will remove any name/address issues.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a mistake on my part. Corrected.